# SSRS 2008 on Chrome Browser show up only in a part of whole webpage

Tags: google-chrome, ssrs-2008

I am trying to open a SSRS report on Chrome. But due to some obscure reason it doesn't open up properly in Chrome. It shows up, but it shows up only in part of the whole webpage. It doesn't render to fit the whole webpage.However this does work fine with Firefox.

Details:
Chrome Version: Version 48.0.2564.103 (64-bit)

SSRS: 2008

OS: Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Below is the screenshot of it. 
[image: SSRS 2008 Report Screenshot on Chrome Browser]
**NOTE:** This is not a duplicate issue. Since the report does show up. Unlike the other issues where it was not showing up at all.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance - Deb

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has been notoriously difficult displaying SSRS reports for me.

Here are some suggestions/things you could try:

Check and make sure [Javascript is enabled in Chrome](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en)

Install [the IE Tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) for Google Chrome

Make sure your [chrome settings and environment meets requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)